# #nav css affecting all elements in page

Tags: css

Hey guys I set up this CSS file to use on the navbar:

```
#nav
{
    background-color: #98bf21;
    } 
#nav li
{
float:left;
}
#nav li ul{
    position: absolute;
    width: 172px;
    left: -999em;
    }

#nav li:hover ul{
    left: auto;
    }   
#nav a:link,a:visited
{
display:block;
width:164px;
font-weight:bold;
color:white;
background-color:#98bf21;
text-align:center;
padding:4px;
text-decoration:none;
text-transform:uppercase;
}
#nav a:hover,a:active
{
background-color: #7A991A;
}
```

And it seems to be affecting all the elements. For example all  elements take the styles if the #nav a styles. Is there something I'm missing here? I'm new to web design.

Comment: You probably forgot to close your `<div id="nav">` somewhere. Try feeding your HTML to the [W3C validator](http://validator.w3.org) and see what happens.

Comment: or maybe you need to clear: both; the element after the navigation

Comment: You also need to structure your code more neatly. It's a mess right now, difficult to read.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`#nav a:link,a:visited` and `#nav a:hover,a:active` look like they could be the problem (the second selector is not bound to `#nav` in those lines and so will be matching all `a` elements. I'm assuming you mean to do `#nav a:link, #nav a:visited` and `#nav a:hover, #nav a:active` instead.

Comment: From the description there is likely to be something wrong in the HTML code also, but this is definitely what's wrong with the CSS code shown.